# NumberFormatException

Tags: java, swing, applet, imageicon

can anybody tell me whats wrong?
i keep getting the numberformatexception when i try to run this program.
here is my action listener.

```
private class ButtonListener implements ActionListener
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        String actionCommand = e.getActionCommand();

        String s = t2.getText();
        int r = Integer.parseInt("s");

        if (t1.getText().equals("1") && (r <= 19)){

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "sdskd");
        }
```

Comment: I'm going to wager that since there's no way to "run that program" ... that's the problem. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/

Comment: Check out some hello world applet's and you will get your answer.

Comment: Aside from what's already been mentioned, there's a big difference between `Integer.parseInt("s");` (what you have) and `Integer.parseInt(s);` (which is what i wager you meant to do)

Answer (score 1):

Few notes about your code

- Your code is not extending the JApplet
- You are not implementing the `public void sart()` method.
- You are not implementing the `public void init()` method.
- And most importantly you are missing [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/)

Answer (score 1):

The image is accessible as an URL from either the class-path or the document base.  An applet will typically not be able to load an image from the client PC, which is what that applet is trying to do.

### Other tips:

1. For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).
2. Ensure the [Java Console](http://www.java.com/en/download/help/javaconsole.xml) is configured to show for applets & JWS apps.  If there is no output at the default level, raise it and try again.